# SharePoint Alerts Vs Custom workflow

Tags: workflow, alert

how to create a workflow to send daily summary emails? OOTB SharePoint Alerts doesn't have capacity to include all the required columns from the list. it just shows what, when and who. this doesn't meet what i want to achieve.
to be more detailed,
in a forms lib, when a new item is added, all the fields of the forms are included in the summary email, but for items that are modified it shows only the specific column and what when who information of the modified field. 
Please let me know if you want me the explain more.

Answer (score 0):

This would be really challenging for a workflow. Workflows are designed to be run based on an event, such as adding or modifying an item in a list. Personally, I'd go the powershell route, or if you're in office 365, the Azure Function route. Both of these can be set to run on a schedule, and can easily query a list for changes, and email any metadata in any format to any set of users.

Comment: i am on O365/sharepoint online. can you give me more information on what do you mean by azure function route. As you know, it is complete online where would i run a PS script if i need it run daily.

Comment: There are a couple ways of running code based on a schedule in azure. You can use powershell from "Azure WebJobs", or C# from "Azure Functions". here's an example in the docs of creating an azure function that runs on a schedule: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-an-event-processing-function

Comment: Or, another writeup is here that gives an overview of using PowerShell to connect to SharePoint online from an Azure Function: https://mikesnotebook.wordpress.com/2017/05/02/creating-an-azure-function-to-act-as-a-sharepoint-timer-job/

Comment: If you are on Office 365 you can try and use Flow for recurrence tasks.  http://www.sharepointing.co.uk/2017/04/29/auto-move-sharepoint-list-items-using-flow/

Comment: Flow doesnt support looking for specific column. Again, it supports only at file level and basic list and library not all list types